# Trouble preparing statements in PDO. Apostrophe errors.

Tags: php, pdo

I'm having trouble preparing a query. I'm getting an error when the $artistname has an apostrophe.

The $keyword can handle apostrophes just fine. What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

```
  $keyword[':keyword'.$x] = "%".$name_single."%";

  $where .= '`name` LIKE :keyword'.$x; 
  if ($name_count!=$x) {
    $where .= ' AND ';
  }

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM `mixtapes` WHERE ".$where." AND name != '$artistname' ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 40";
  $search = $db->prepare($sql);
  $search->execute($keyword);
```

Comment: instead of `!=` use `<>`

Comment: Please take a few moments to do a search to see if your question already has an answer before asking it.

Comment: I did @RiggsFolly, I was just having problems with this particular case. I was probably look to hard for the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well Your prepare statement is not preparing artistname. When using prepare statement, You put placeholders in query and then execute passing variables to query. Add artisname to array and You should be fine.

```
$keyword[':keyword'.$x] = "%".$name_single."%";

$where .= '`name` LIKE :keyword'.$x; 
if ($name_count!=$x) {
  $where .= ' AND ';
}

$keyword[':artistname'] = $artistname;

$sql = "SELECT * FROM `mixtapes` WHERE ".$where." AND name != :artistname ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 40";
$search = $db->prepare($sql);
$search->execute($keyword);
```